# facing Issue in parsing in swift3

Tags: swift

[image]
I am trying to parse the emergency data in into emergency struct but it never statifies the condition and get into else case.Here is my code and structure.Some thing i have written woring in first line.

```
   if let emergencyDict = snapshotValue["emergency"]  as? [String:[String:Any]]{
        for (emerId, emerData) in emergencyDict {
            let emer = Emergency.init(emergency: emerData as NSDictionary)
            emergency.append(emer)
        }
    }
    else{
        let emer = Emergency.init(emerg: "" as AnyObject)
        emergency.append(emer)
    }


struct Emergency{
var emer_id: String
var emer_name: String
var emer_phoneNo: String

init(emergency: NSDictionary) {

    if emergency.object(forKey: "id") != nil {
        emer_id = emergency.object(forKey: "id") as! String
    }
    else{
        emer_id = ""
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having `emergency` as Array with type `[Any]` and if you remove the first object then you get Array of type `[[String:Any]]`. So try like this way.

```
if let array = snapshotValue["emergency"]  as? [Any], 
   let emergencyArrar = Array(array.dropFirst()) as? [[String:Any]] {

    print(emergencyArray)
    for emergency in emergencyArray {
         print(emergency)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have written wrong in this line:

```
if let emergencyDict = snapshotValue["emergency"]  as? [String:[String:Any]]{
```

It should be:

```
if let emergencyDict = snapshotValue["emergency"]  as? [[String:Any]]{
```

Comment: When i am trying to print 
print(snapshotValue["emergency"] ?? AnyObject.self)
then it o/p is:
(
    "<null>",
        {
        id = 1;
        name = father;
        phoneNo = 01828020209;
    },
        {
        id = 2;
        name = mother;
        phoneNo = 12345678;
    }
)

Comment: Right. First element of your array is null, so you'll have to drop it. Try @NiravD 's solution

Answer (score 0):

This question should belong to query from firebase database.

```
// you have to get the children in emergency, 
// then get the value(dictionary) of each child
ref.child("emergency").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let keys = value?.allKeys // [1, 2, 3 ....]

        for key in keys {
            ref.child("emergency").child(key)..observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                 let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                 // Here is your dictionary
            }
        }


    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```